# How to upgrade SQL Server 2017 CU4 without Internet Access?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Does anyone know how to upgrade SQL Server 2017 to CU4 without Internet access?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this URL ?
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56128

It downloads a file with 473 MB

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Pedro, but it still need background download for Python server and R server